# How to add new values to an already initialized object[][] in Java?

Tags: java, android

How do I add new values to an initialized object?

```
Object[][] myData = new Object[][]{{1,2}, {3,4}};
int number1 = 5;
int number2 = 6;
```

In the code above, I have to add `number1` and `number2` in `myData`. How can I do that?

Comment: `[][]` is a 2-dimensional array. You can't extend an array in fact. You have to create new one with larger length. Go through Java basics of how to work with arrays.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use ArrayList rather than arrays. Arrays have fixed length and can’t be added to.

Comment: Array size is immutable in Java. What you need can pass by a ArrayList, where you can add or remove elements without major concern about size

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create another bigger array and copy the items from the old array to the new array then add the new items to it.

A better alternative is to use an ArrayList. When you add items to an ArrayList, the capacity will grow behind the scenes if needed; you don't have to worry about increasing the size.

> Using your code

```
Object[][] myData = new Object[][]{{1,2}, {3,4}};
int number1 = 5;
int number2 = 6;
Object[][] bigNewArray =  Arrays.copyOf(myData, myData.length +1 );
/*
  The +1 is to increase the size of the new created array, 
  you can increae it to how many numbers you want and datas accordingly. 
*/
bigNewArray[2] = new Object[]{number1, number2};
System.out.println(bigNewArray[2][0]); //Print out 5
```

> Using ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Object[]> myData1 = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
Object[] one = new Object[]{1,2};
Object[] two = new Object[]{3,4};
Object[] three = new Object[]{5,6};

myData1.add(one);
myData1.add(two);
myData1.add(three);
//you can add as many object to it as you want
System.out.println(myData1.get(2)[0]); //Print out 5
```

Comment: Sample added to answer